# Using Variable- Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsqldeveloper

In the above code, I am giving schemaname as input and using that input it should connect to the database. But In this case the value i entered is not taken by the schemaname. This is how the out put and the error is:

```
declare schemaname varchar2(20);
exec :schemaname := XYZ;
BEGIN

end;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref
   char time timestamp interval date binary national character
   nchar
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONNECT" when expecting one of the following:
```

Could any one suggest how to make it work using spool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code between `declare` and `end` is PL/SQL. Commands like `CONNECT` or `SPOOL` are SQL*Plus commands. You cannot use SQL*Plus commands in a PL/SQL block.

In your case you don't need PL/SQL at all:

Create a script with following content

```
connect &1
spool C:\ABC
@c:\ABC
spool off;
```

and run it

```
@your_script_name
```

BTW: there is no reason to run script c:\ABC while you are spooling into it. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: The spool will default to `C:\ABC.LST` as no suffix was given; the `@` will default to `C:\ABC.SQL`. So they aren't the same file. I'd prefer to see at least the spool name in full though to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 1):

[`exec[ute]`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) is SQL*Plus and SQL Developer (and maybe other clients) shorthand for an anonymous block. It is a *client* command, it is not part of PL/SQL. You are trying to use it inside a PL/SQL declare section, where it is not valid or recognised.

If you want a client bind variable you need the [`var[iable]` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm):

```
var schemaname varchar2(20);
exec :schemaname := '&1';

BEGIN
...
```

Notice the single quotes around `&1`, as it's being assigned to a string variable.

But you can't connect inside a PL/SQL block either, and you can't use a bind variable for the connection.

```
connect :schemaname
```

will prompt for a password (even if you defined it's value as `user/passwd`) and try to connect as a user lieterally called `:schemaname`.

You can use a substituion variable, but you don't really need to define a new one; as you seem to be passing the credentials in, you can do:

```
connect &1
```

(without surrounding quotes)